# Regular expressions in xpaths

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath

I am using Java and Selenium.  The HTML designers did not give really useful IDs.  I need to access an element with the following:

```
<span id="gridcolumn-1040-textInnerEl"
```

I can use

```
//span[contains(@id, 'gridcolumn') and (contains(@id, 'textInnerEl'))]
```

for the xpath but this can get complicated (this is a simpler example).  is there any way to use a regexp in an xpath such as the following:

```
//span[match(@id, '^gridcolumn-[%d]+-testInnerEl$']
```

to avoid multiple *and contains(@id,...)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath` to match `span` by `regex`:

```
//span[matches(@id, '^gridcolumn-\d+-textInnerEl$')]
```

Comment: Trying it now one two

Comment: oh... Yes. AFAIK `Selenium` supports `XPath 1.0` only while `matches()` is from `XPath 2.0`... I didn't pay attention to `selenium` tag(

Comment: This would answer my question if I had xpath 2 ;-)  So I will check it.  Will Chrome ever use it?

Comment: I hope it will in following `webdriver` versions. It can significantly increase flexibility of selectors

Answer (score 0):

A combination of three functions `starts-with()`, `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` will give you the chance to select desired element:

```
//span[starts-with(@id, 'gridcolumn') and number(substring-before(substring-after(@id, '-'), '-')) = substring-before(substring-after(@id, '-'), '-') and substring-after(substring-after(@id, '-'), '-') = 'textInnerEl']
```

Comment: Thanks.  Then I could just use two contains() ;-)

Comment: How `contains()` can assure you the *middle* part is always *digits*?